# Symbol for bitwise circular shifts

Tags: assembly, operators, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

C and some other languages have [bitwise shifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts). They usually have at least logical shifts (actually those are arithmetic when using them to signed integers and logical when integers are unsigned)[[source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23_and_Python):

- shift left (`<<`)
- shift right (`>>`)

In Java there is also an logical shift right (`>>>`). There is no separate logical shift right, because its the same as arithmetic shift right. [[source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_Java)

When coding assembly language I sometimes need *circular shifts* (`crc`, `crl`, `ror` and `rol`). Sometimes I'd like to note them as symbols instead of letter combinations when planning or writing documentation. I was unable to find any symbols for them.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Circular_rotates_in_C_and_C.2B.2B):

> There are also compiler-specific intrinsics implementing circular shifts, like _rotl8, _rotl16, _rotr8, _rotr16 in Microsoft Visual C++. Clang provides some rotate intrinsics for Microsoft compatibility that suffers the problems above.[9] GCC does not offer rotate intrinsics.

**Are there established symbols for bitwise circular shifts?**

Comment: What do you mean, "There is no arithmetic shift right, because its the same as logical shift right"? Do you mean that in C there is no arithmetic shift right? There are no rotation operators in C. If such functionality exists, it would be a function call.

Comment: I assume he meant left shifts.

Comment: There's a mathematical programming language called APL (A Programming Language), dating back to the 1960's. It has a lot of operators and uses symbols for those operators. There is a rotate operator, but it applies to vectors, matrices, or any multi-dimensional array, and uses the symbol large circle with vertical bar for rotate along last dimension, large circle with horizontal bar for rotate along first dimension, or a index is used to select which dimension to rotate. A positive left argument means rotate left, a negative one means rotate right. This only applies to APL, not general math.

Comment: Yep, I know APL, but using those operators is real pain when you are trying to write using moder computer with qwerty keyboard. Also that operator is not bitwise rotate operator but list rotate.

Answer (score 0):

`>>>` is actually the logical shift in Java. As far as I know, that notation isn't common in computer science literature, only in Java and Java-inspired languages that lack unsigned types.

Rotates are sometimes written out as ROTL or some variant of that, or expressed as multiplication by a power of two modulo a power of two minus one, or as `<<` with the word "rot" above it (seen in Hacker's Delight), but the most common is `<<<` which appears in many cryptography texts though more commonly in their diagrams (`>>>` is also sometimes seen, but it is less common). In order to avoid ambiguity with Java, you can limit yourself to `<<<`, or just define them in your introduction or perhaps in a footnote.